# ROS_Matlab subscriber

Tags: ros, matlab, rosmatlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using Matlab/ROS interface (with Matlab R2013a and ROS fuerte)

I've done the Matlab example where a node publish and subscriber from Matalb and this example works without problem.
But now I have gazebo running and I want to subscrib from Matlab and It doesn't work.. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

I do:
roscore

roslaunch gazebo_world ....

and execute this code from Matlab:

global rosMasterIp;
rosMasterIp = '127.0.1.1';

global localhostIp;
localhostIp = '127.0.0.1';

% Create a new node named /NODE and connect it to the master.

node = rosmatlab.node('NODE', rosMasterIp, 11311, 'rosIP', localhostIp);

% Add a publisher of a topic named /TOPIC to the node to send message of type std_msgs/String.

publisher = rosmatlab.publisher('TOPIC','std_msgs/String',node);

% Add a subscriber to a topic named /TOPIC to the node to receive message

subscriber  = rosmatlab.subscriber('TOPIC','std_msgs/String',1,node)

%Gazebo topic

subscriber2 = rosmatlab.subscriber('gazebo/model_states', 'gazebo_msgs/ModelStates',1,node);

subscriber.setOnNewMessageListeners({@function1});
subscriber2.setOnNewMessageListeners({@function2});

% Create a new message of type std_msgs/String.

msg = rosmatlab.message('std_msgs/String',node);

% Set the data field of the message and then publish the message

msg.setData(sprintf('Message created: %s',datestr(now)));

publisher.publish(msg);
pause(1);

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145276/ros_matlab-subscriber/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I added two lines to ~/.bashrc to make sure roscore has a predictable URI:**

export ROS_IP=192.168.1.11  <== your computer's IP

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.11:11311

**To connect in MATLAB:**

```
% Run the rosmatlab setup scripts

addpath([matlabroot '/toolbox/psp/rosmatlab/']);

rosmatlab_SetPath;

rosmatlab_AddClassPath;

% Connect to roscore which should be running in a terminal

node = rosmatlab.node('MATLAB_NODE', '192.168.1.11', 11311);

% Subscribe to the 'state' topic to receive updates on the state.

% The message type is lyap_control/plant

subscriber = rosmatlab.subscriber('state', 'lyap_control/plant', 1, node);
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2015-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on 2015-03-02**:
Does it work or not??
I can't subscribe from Matlab to ros topic, it seems to be unidirectional.
Please, let me know if you solved it and share the full solution!
thanks!!!

**Comment by [ziyeshanwai](https://answers.ros.org/users/21973/ziyeshanwai/) on 2015-03-28**:
I want to know ,too.I meet the same problem give you a link,maybe can help you  [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/130356/how-to-subscribe-to-topics-using-ros-support-from-matlab/?answer=132381#post-id-132381)

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2015-03-28**:
Yeah, it works, guys. Have you tried it? Make sure the ip that you specify with ROS_IP is your computer's current IP.

**Comment by [ziyeshanwai](https://answers.ros.org/users/21973/ziyeshanwai/) on 2015-03-29**:
Yes,I have tried.I worked!